# Super Lie-infinity algebra of closed superstring field theory?

Tags: string-theory, research-level

Bosonic closed [string field theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string+field+theory) is [famously governed](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string%20field%20theory#ReferencesHomotopyAlgebra) by a [Lie n-algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/L-infinity+algebra) for $n = \infty$ whose $k$-ary bracket is given by the genus-0 (k+1)-point function in the BRST complex of the string.

One might therefore expect that, analogously, closed *superstring* field theory (in any of its variants) is governed by a lift of that to a [super Lie n-algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/super+L-infinity+algebra) for $n = \infty$.

The closest to an identification of such that I am aware of is in

- Yuji Okawa, Barton Zwiebach, *Heterotic String Field Theory* ([arXiv:hep-th/0406212](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0406212))

where substructures of the bosonic string field $L_\infty$-algebra are paired with the super-ingredients. This seems to go in the right direction, but does not quite identify a super $L_\infty$-algebra structure.

Is there, meanwhile, anything more known that may complete the picture here?

Comment: Why do you use both "$L_\infty$-algebra" and "Lie $n$-algebra for $n = \infty$", when the article you linked indicates that they are the same thing?  Is there a subtle distinction I am missing?

Comment: There is indeed no distinction, and that's what I wanted to implicitly emphasize a little, with an eye towards the BLG "3-algebra" excitement http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/BLG+model#3AlgebraStructure.

Comment: Superstring field theory actually works differently than this "straightforward" generalization of bosonic string field theory.

Comment: There is an answer at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/4978